# Python: combine datafiles

Tags: python, netcdf, combine, evi

How can I combine two files to one file with python? I want to combine two files with different area and create them in one file.

This file was `modis`(evi) convert `hdf`(sinusoidal projection) to `netcdf`(geoprojection) file by GDAL.

```
[<xarray.Dataset>    
                                                                                                                                                      
** Dimensions:  (lat: 2784, lon: 9907) **                                                                                                                                       
Coordinates:                                                                                                                                                               
  * lat      (lat) float64 40.0 40.01 40.01 40.01 ... 49.99 49.99 49.99 50.0                                                                                               
  * lon      (lon) float64 104.4 104.4 104.4 104.4 ... 140.0 140.0 140.0 140.0                                                                                             
Data variables:                                                                                                                                                            
    evi      (lat, lon) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(2784, 9907), meta=np.ndarray>                                                                                        
    crs      |S1 ...                                                                                                                                                       
Attributes:                                                                                                                                                                
    Conventions:  CF-1.5                                                                                                                                                   
    GDAL:         GDAL 3.2.1, released 2020/12/29                                                                                                                          
    history:      Thu May 11 06:23:47 2023: ncrename -v Band1,evi /h3/data/ni...                                                                                           
    NCO:          netCDF Operators version 4.9.3 (Homepage = http://nco.sf.ne..., <xarray.Dataset>                                                                         


**Dimensions:  (lat: 3032, lon: 8985)   **                                                                                                                                     
Coordinates:                                                                                                                                                               
  * lat      (lat) float64 30.0 30.01 30.01 30.01 ... 39.99 39.99 40.0 40.0                                                                                                
  * lon      (lon) float64 127.0 127.0 127.0 127.0 ... 156.6 156.6 156.6 156.6                                                                                             
Data variables:                                                                                                                                                            
    evi      (lat, lon) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(3032, 8985), meta=np.ndarray>                                                                                        
    crs      |S1 ...                                                                                                                                                       
Attributes:                                                                                                                                                                
    Conventions:  CF-1.5                                                                                                                                                   
    GDAL:         GDAL 3.2.1, released 2020/12/29                                                                                                                          
    history:      Thu May 11 07:11:37 2023: ncrename -v Band1,evi /h3/data/ni...                                                                                           
    NCO:          netCDF Operators version 4.9.3 (Homepage = http://nco.sf.ne..., <xarray.Dataset>
```